# changes to the LGPO thru gpedit.msc on domain connected machines do not apply after restarts and gpupdate /force

Tags: windows-registry, group-policy, microphone, windows-domain, windows-10-v1803

FYI I am very new to the world of system administration.  However I have been able to find answers to nearly every question that has come across my desk - till now.

We have LGPO policy's set manually on our machines to prevent unauthorized access of hardware.  Specifically "Let Windows apps access the Microphone" which has been set for Enabled -Force Deny.  This has been perfectly fine until the recent 1803 update.

When you change the gpedit.msc setting to "force allow" or "not configured" it seems to take a few days for the settings to take affect.  Even after restarting the laptop repeatedly (5 times) and running gpupdate /force through command prompt.  I have even gone so far as to delete all of the group policy files from C:\Windows\System32\grouppolicy and grouppolicyusers.
To top it off I started running a script to manually change the registry setting to force allow.

What gives!  Nothing I do seems to apply the changes immediately.  We are planning on dumping our domain entirely w/in the next year but for my own education and sanity I must understand this conundrum.  Why is there a delay?  What can I do to circumvent this issue.